# Statistics - two sample independent t-test unequal sample size

Tags: t-test, small-sample

Hypothetically speaking, if I was conducting an independent t-test and my two samples had different sample sizes, let's say sample A had 21 data points and sample B had 52. what would the n value be when calculating the t stat?

Comment: There are two $n$s: $n_{1}$ and $n_{2}$.  There is one parameter for the (denominator) degrees of freedom for the test: $n_{1}+n_{2}-2$.  Not sure why you would even note whether $n$s are equal.  More key is  what is your experimental design and are the two samples comparable in all other ways.